# Using Node's REQUEST to render an AJAX page

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, web-scraping

I'm using Node's `Request` module: https://github.com/mikeal/request

I'm trying to load in a page that has data populated via AJAX/other post-loading server side processes. Here's an 
example: http://www.jcrew.com/mens_category/polostees/slimshop/PRDOVR~96239/96239.jsp

If you view source, you'll notice that most of the page is missing from the source (which is what `Request` returns). Things like the price and sizing information are not available.

Is it at all possible to get this info using Node (preferably using `request`)? Or am I stuck with the incomplete output?

Edit: Perhaps give some feedback before downvoting and closing?

Comment: What you want is a headless browser in order to be be able to execute client javascript on the webpage. You should look into [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [CasperJS](casperjs.org).

Comment: Yes, PhantomJS helps. But maybe you can just set the `User-Agent` header to some bot and the pages you scan switch to non-AJAX pages delivering all the content in one page, because they think you are not a browser, which is true obviously. But this is not in your hand, it depends on the web-site. With Google Chrome you can fake the User-Agent header and see if it works.

Comment: @hgoebl Great idea. Which header specifically would I set?

Comment: I tested it on this special page and it didn't work. But generally one could do `request.get({ url: url, headers: { "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" }}, ...`. Remark: I don't know whether it is ok to fake Googlebot, so be careful.